# "sparkContext was shut down" while running spark on a large dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql

When running sparkJob on a cluster past a certain data size(~2,5gb) I am getting either "Job cancelled because SparkContext was shut down" or "executor lost". When looking at yarn gui I see that job that got killed was successful. There are no problems when running on data that is 500mb. I was looking for a solution and found that:
  - "seems yarn kills some of the executors as they request more memory than expected."

Any suggestions how to debug it?

command that I submit my spark job with:

```
/opt/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit  --driver-memory 22g --driver-cores 4 --num-executors 15 --executor-memory 6g --executor-cores 6  --class sparkTesting.Runner   --master yarn-client myJar.jar jarArguments
```

and sparkContext settings

```
val sparkConf = (new SparkConf()
    .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "21g")
    .set("spark.akka.frameSize", "2011")
    .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
    .set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true")
    .set("spark.eventLog.dir", configVar.sparkLogDir)
    )
```

Simplified code that fails looks like that

```
 val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
val broadcastParser = sc.broadcast(new Parser())

val featuresRdd = hc.sql("select "+ configVar.columnName + " from " + configVar.Table +" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " + configVar.Articles)
val myRdd : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = featuresRdd.map(doSomething(_,broadcastParser))

val allWords= featuresRdd
  .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .count

val wordQuantiles= featuresRdd
  .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map(pair => (pair._2 , pair._2))
  .reduceByKey(_+_)
  .sortBy(_._1)
  .collect
  .scanLeft((0,0.0)) ( (res,add) => (add._1, res._2+add._2) )
  .map(entry => (entry._1,entry._2/allWords))

val dictionary = featuresRdd
  .flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _) // here I have Rdd of word,count tuples
  .filter(_._2 >= moreThan)
  .filter(_._2 <= lessThan)
  .filter(_._1.trim!=(""))
  .map(_._1)
  .zipWithIndex
  .collect
  .toMap
```

And Error stack

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:703)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:702)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:702)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1511)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$7.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1715)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1185)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1714)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1839)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1910)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
at sparkTesting.InputGenerationAndDictionaryComputations$.createDictionary(InputGenerationAndDictionaryComputations.scala:50)
at sparkTesting.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:133)
at sparkTesting.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: In my experience this is nearly always due to OOM exceptions. Try to have a look at the log files on the individual executor machines.

Comment: I would printstacktrace from your job and monitor JVM Heap size with some Java util tools: jstat, jstatd, jconsole ... to find out more about the limitation. In case you still have physical memory you can increase the JVM memory size before starting your app! You can resize your collections based on your optimised Heap size.

Comment: I have this problem in pyspark too, In my case, this is due to lack of memory in container, we can Resize memory when start a spark instance use the parameter `--executor.memory YOUR_MEMORY_SIZE`. if your spark is run on `hadoop`, this value cannot exceed the value `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` set by yarn.    the default value of `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` is 8192MB in **hadoop 2.7.7** . In my case, I use this command to run pyspark: `pyspark --master yarn --executor.memory`, solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the answer.

The my table was saved as a 20gb avro file. When executors tried to open it. Each of them had to load 20gb into memory. Solved it by using csv instead of avro

Answer (score 8):

Symptoms are typical of a OutOfMemory error in one the executor tasks. Try augmenting memory for executor when lauching job. See parameter  --executor-memory of spark-submit, spark-shell etc. Default value is 1G

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause of the "SparkContext is shutdown" error is that you are importing a jar file after evaluating some other code. (This may only happen in Spark Notebook.)

To fix the problem, move all your `:cp myjar.jar` statements to the start of your file.

Comment: Please suggest ways to improve this post before downvoting it. Thank you!